# What is the correct etymology of 백정?

Tags: etymology

According to [the 백정 Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baekjeong), the etymology of 백정 is:

> It consists of "Baek"(Korean: 백, Hanja: 白), which means 'no', and "Jeong(Korean: 정, Hanja: 丁)", which means a person without land.

In Wiktionary I cannot find these meanings for [백](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%B0%B1) or [정](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%A0%95). Perhaps they stem from ancient usages of 백 and 정?

Perhaps the Korean Wiktionary has these meanings for [백](https://ko.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%B0%B1) and 
[정](https://ko.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%A0%95)? Unfortunately I cannot read Korean so I cannot check.

Note: The reference Wikipedia gives for this etymology is [Kim, Joong Seop (2013). ""조선시대 백정"의 기원에 대한 역사사회학적 고찰"](http://kiss.kstudy.com/thesis/thesis-view.asp?key=3197916) . [Articles : The Origins of the Outcast, Paekjong, in the Choson Period: The Socio-Historical Perspective Reconsidered].동방학지. 164: 140~141 – via 연세대학교 국학연구원(Yonsei Univ. Oriental Institute).

Answer (score 2):

This is a loanword from Literary Chinese, attested as far back as the Sui dynasty, and subsequently quoted in the Kangxi Dictionary of 1710:

> 《北史·李敏傳》周宣帝謂樂平公主曰：敏何官。對曰：一**白丁**耳。又白民。

One of the meanings for 白, literally *white* (eumhun: 흰 백), is listed under no. 7 on [Naver's Hanja dictionary](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/hanja?q=%E7%99%BD):

> 7. 비다, (가진 것이)없다

English translation: *to be empty*, (of things in possession) *to not have*

A more complete hangeul-to-hanja list is found after you click "see more" in Naver's Hanja dictionary. Hence for 정, [we have:](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/search/keyword?query=%EC%A0%95)

> **丁** 고무래 정,장정 정

The 장정 meaning (literally *able-bodied/fit man*) is the one the applies here, and is also found on [WIktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%9E%A5%EC%A0%95).

Comment: Then it would seem the Wikipedia article is wrong? It says *"a person without land"*, rather then *"an unfit person"*?

Comment: @Johan88 No - I think it's fine: "an able-bodied man without [something]" - land is assumed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Each house was called '정호(**丁**戶)' which meant a householder owes duties of tax, military and labours to the country. '백정호(**白丁**戶)' has the 백(白- white) letter and it means a householder is free from duty.

> 현대의 인식으로는 옛날에 소나 돼지 등 동물을 잡고 해체해서 파는 일을 했었던 사람으로서, 조선시대에는 완전히 별개의 존재였던 노비를 제외한 양인 중에서는 최하급 계층이었으며 대개의 경우 현대에서 백정이라는 단어는 부정적으로 인식되고 있다.
>   그러나 정확하게 도축, 발골, 정형을 담당하는 사람이 역사적으로 백정이라고 불린 것은 조선시대 세종 이후의 일이었다. 그 전에는 백정은 일반 백성을 의미하는 단어였으며 조선 세종 이후 백정이 다른 뜻으로 바뀐 후에도 도축업자가 백정일 수는 있었지만 모든 백정이 다 도축업자는 아니었다. 도축업자는 백정의 일부였으며 도축업 이외에도 다른 직업군을 포괄하고 있는 다른의미의 단어였다. 
>   어원은 중국 수(隨)나라에서 온 말로 당시 뜻은 그냥 일반 백성을 뜻하였을 뿐이다. **나라에서 군인이나 향리 등의 직역을 부여한 집을 정호(丁戶)라 불렀고, 여기에 포함되지 않는 집을 백정호(白丁戶)라고 불렀다. 여기서 백은 하얗다는 의미가 아니라, '00이 아니다'라는 의미이다.**
>   그렇다면 우리가 알게된 백정은 어디서 온 사람들일까 바로 고려시대 화척이라고 불리는 무리들이였다. 
>   수척(水尺)·무자리라고도 한다. 신라 말 고려 초 혼란기에 유입되었던 북방의 유목민들 즉 양수척(楊水尺)이 고려 후기에 이르러 화척으로 불렸다가 조선 초에는 백정(白丁)이라고 바뀌어 불렸다. 화척은 집단으로 유랑하면서 걸식, 강도, 방화, 살인 등을 자행하였다. 고려 말의 홍건적 침입 때에는 길잡이 노릇을 하였으며, 왜구를 가장해 민가를 약탈하기도 하였다. 1356년(공민왕 5)에는 나라에서 화척을 비롯해 제주 사람과 재인을 모두 찾아내어 서북면 수졸(戍卒)로 충당하기도 하였다. 화척이 서북면 지역 군사로 충당되거나 왜구를 사칭해 노략질을 일삼았던 것은 그들의 유목민적 기질과 농경에 정착하지 못해 항산(恒産)이 없는 열악한 처지를 말해주는 사례이다.
>   화척은 호적에 등록되어 있지 않았기 때문에 국가 지배를 받는 공민(公民)의 대우를 받지 못하였다. 조선 태조 이후 성종 때까지 조정은 이들을 호적에 올려 파악하려고 하거나 토지를 지급해 농업을 생업으로 삼도록 하였고, 그러한 자에게는 신공을 면제시켜주는 정책을 계속 펴나갔다. 아울러 독립된 집단 생활과 자기들끼리의 혼인을 금지시키는 한편, 일반 양인과 함께 살게 하면서 혼인을 장려하였다. 또한 지방 관아에서 이들을 찾아내 각 방(坊)과 촌(村)별로 보호하게 하고, 장적을 만들어 형조·한성부·감영 및 각 고을에 보관했다가 출생·사망·도망 등의 사항을 기재하도록 하는 등 철저히 점검하였다

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That's quite a different etymology.. What's the source of your info?

Comment: This is the source [ https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B0%B1%EC%A0%95 ]. It's kind of Wiki for Korean. Unfortunately, there is no translation yet.

Comment: Thanks so much. It would seem to me then, rightly or wrongly, that I have 3 etymologies: *"a person without land", "an unfit person", "(a householder) without duty (of tax)".* Don't know if I'm right in my assessment, and please correct me if I'm wrong, because it seems Michaelyus thinks I'm wrong, and I don't know Korean or Chinese or their grammars so it's quite impossible for me to judge.

Answer (score 1):

백정 originally referred to "commoners" or "people (mainly, farmers) without 정인's duty (e.g. military service)" according to [this](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0022351):

> 백정: 고려시대 **군역(軍役)**·기인역(其人役)·역역(驛役) 등의 특정한 직역(職役)을 부담하지 않고 주로 농업에 종사하던 **농민층**.
>
> 백정이라는 명칭은 원래 중국의 남북조와 수(隋)나라에서는 무관자인 **평민**, 즉 백성을 일컫던 말이다.
>
> 백정의 ‘백(白)’은 ‘없다’ 또는 ‘아니다’라는 의미를 지닌 말이고, ‘정(丁)’은 ‘정호(丁戶)’ 또는 ‘정인(丁人)’이라는 뜻이므로 백정은 **정호(정인)가 아닌 사람**을 지칭한다.

군역 means (the duty of) military service.
농민층 means the class of farmers.
백정 also had duties such as paying taxes.

As SanghyunPark mentioned, 백정 had referred to one who is *not* 정호 or 정인. Michaelyus correctly guessed the meaning of 백(白). You assumed that 백정 meant "an unfit person"; however, that is *incorrect.*

According to [a publication (written in English)](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=AOu5BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA69), the citizens called 백정 (Bai Ding) were *mostly* composed of *land-holding farmers*. Thus, 백정 did *not* mean "a person without land." Please read it from "the common citizens" to "legal privileges" on page 69.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. It seems the meaning of the word evolved over time, and I'm not sure what the etymological origin is then (as opposed to the things it came to mean). But your finding is quite the contrast to the Wikipedia article which says *""Jeong (Korean: 정, Hanja: 丁)", which means a person without land"*.

Comment: @Johan88 I think the author(s) made a mistake there. 백정 was a person without *granted* land. 백정 did not receive land from the kingdom, but they could possess land. It's just that not every 백정 had land. 백정 without land rented land to farm, which means a certain group of 백정 was tenant farmers.